# Issue with sending file using Spring WebClient to MobfsApi

Tags: java, spring, api, runtime-error, webclient

I'm trying to send an apk file using the spring web client for static analysis to the mobfs api service. But I am getting an error with json response  `{"error": {"file": "This field is required."}}`.

This is an example cUrl from doc.

> curl -F 'file=@/Users/ajin/Desktop/diva-beta.apk'
> http://localhost:8000/api/v1/upload -H
> "X-Mobsf-Api-Key:bbe2a81af7e42b82222bbfe4fcf54d681dbc1ba34ef6d41a17ce1881cfda0709"

```
  File file = new File("/light.apk");

  ContentDisposition contentDisposition = ContentDisposition
                .builder("form-data")
                .name("file")
                .filename("light.apk")
                .build();

  return webClient.post()
                .uri(UPLOAD_FILE_URL)
                .header("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition.toString())
                .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(fromFile(file)))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .block();

    }

    public MultiValueMap<String, HttpEntity<?>> fromFile(File file) {
        MultipartBodyBuilder builder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
        builder.part("file", new FileSystemResource(file));
        return builder.build();
    }
```

Logs:

[image: logs]

What am I doing wrong?